# Load xml row into 2D array

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, arrays

So I have this xml

```
<document>
  <Month>
    <Depth>-0,25</Depth>
    <October>0,95</October>
    <November>-0,90</November>
    ...
  </Month>
  <Month>
    <Depth>-0,5</Depth>
    <October>0,47</October>
    <November>-0,17</November>
    ...
  </Month>
  ...
</document>
```

I've searched a bit and I saw some way to do it with linq but only with a 1D array, becasue what I would like to eventually end up with would be

```
Array[0,0] = -0.25
Array[0,1] = 0.95
Array[0,2] = -0.90
...
```

Comment: Do you have to have a `double[,]` or could it be a `double[][]`? (Also note that numbers in XML files are typically written using the invariant culture... it's odd to see a `,` as the decimal separator.)

Comment: In my point of view (since I'm not experiemented) it doesn't change anythings between both, but I have no requirement, but I will look to know the difference between both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy with a jagged array (an array of arrays) then LINQ makes it fairly easy:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);
var array = doc.Root
               .Elements("Month")
               .Select(month => month.Elements().Select(x => (double) x).ToArray())
               .ToArray();
```

If you need a rectangular array, that's trickier.

Personally I would actually build a custom type with `Depth`, `October` and `November` properties, rather than relying on the order of the elements within `Month`, but that's a different matter.

Note that the above cast to `double` will (probably?) fail for the values you've got there - more conventional XML would use `.` instead of `,`. However, if it does fail you can use `double.Parse(x.Value, someAppropriateCulture)` instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm canadian, and we use `,`. Is there any major difference betwen a jagged array and a rectangular one ?

Comment: +1. Need special feature on SO "Question already have answer with 600K+ reputation" so others can safely ignore it :)

Comment: @Mokmeuh: You may be Canadian, but XML typically tries to avoid being culture-specific. If you write your data in a standardized way, it'll be easier for others to read it. There are various differences between jagged and rectangular arrays - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: Thank you alot, you have been really helpfull.

Comment: I've just noticed, maybe I've been not clair, sorry if it's the case, but with what you gave me, what's inside the month tag is a column, when I converted them from the excel file I,ve put them as a row, so how can I invert what you did :/ ?

Comment: basicly, each time there's a month tag, it's a definition of a row

Comment: @Mokmeuh: I'd write a separate method to transpose the array. Search on SO and you may well find there already is one.

Comment: Ok thank you, I guess there's no way to do it from the linq parse command

Comment: @Mokmeuh: I hesitate to say there's *no* way of doing it - but I suspect it would be ugly.